# AWS Lambda - Getting path parameters using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

In an AWS lambda written in Node.js, I want to extract the following part of a URL when I do a GET call through the API gateway:

```
/devices/{id} --> {id} will be replaced by a value, and that is the value I want!
```

I know that to get QueryStringParameters you just use

```
event.queryStringParameters.[parameter name]
```

But how will I do this for path parameters, like for {id} above.

Also is there a good place where I can comprehensively learn about writing lambdas for APIs in Node.js?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using lambda proxy here i'm pasting the event object sample for lambda proxy.

```
    {
  "message": "Good day, John of Seattle. Happy Friday!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/Seattle",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "day": "Friday"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "time": "morning"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "Seattle"
    },
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
      "path": "/{proxy+}",
      "accountId": "123456789012",
      "resourceId": "nl9h80",
      "stage": "test-invoke-stage",
      "requestId": "test-invoke-request",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
        "accountId": "123456789012",
        "cognitoIdentityId": null,
        "caller": "AIDXXX...XXVJZG",
        "apiKey": "test-invoke-api-key",
        "sourceIp": "test-invoke-source-ip",
        "accessKey": "ASIXXX...XXDQ5A",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
        "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/kdeding",
        "userAgent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_131)",
        "user": "AIDXXX...XXVJZG"
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "r275xc9bmd"
    },
    "body": "{ \"callerName\": \"John\" }",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

the path can be extracted from "path" key in event object, it can be accessed from event.path and after that you can use string manipulation function to further manipulate it.

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, this does help! Just one question, where do I specify where it should look for the path parameter? For example, If I structure my API to get the id when this url is called: "/devices/{id}", how do I tell aws to assign the string after the second slash to the {id} parameter, or does that happen automatically?

Comment: you don't need to tell explicitly the path parameter will contain whole string passed after the url of your api gateway for example if your api gateway url is example.dev.com and you have called the following url example.dev.com/test/2 then the path parameter would contain /test/2

Comment: Thanks! Also, where did you get the entire event object from?

Comment: lambda will pass data into event object automatically which is present in your handler function

Comment: Why in the world would someone use proxy integration for a single path parameter?

Answer (score 31):

Short answer:

```
const { id } = event.pathParameters;
```

I recently released a short training video that demonstrates in detail how to create API Gateway REST APIs and integrate them with AWS Lambda (NodeJS). Please check it out here:

[Serverless Architecture: AWS API Gateway & Lambda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc1YIOAbyS0)

Answer (score 12):

Use brackets in the resource path, as image above. Then in node.js user the code below:

```
exports.handler = async function(event) {
    let serviceId = event.pathParameters.id;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, proxy integration is a ridiculous solution for a single path parameter.

Comment: This comment is pretty confusing honestly. Proxy integration is required to be checked on in the method in order to pass pathParameters to the event object.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very similar to what you mentioned in the first place. Just use `event.pathParameters` instead of `event.queryStringParameters`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use a curly brace to configure path variable on AWS API Gateway.]

Here I'm using /api/test/{id} as my resource path and using Lambda Proxy integration. I'm getting the following event when I hit https://www.dummyapi.com/dev/api/test/id-123456

[image]

Comment: You can get these details from the lambda code. here you go

<code>
exports.handler =  (event,context, callback) => {  console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));   }
</code>

Comment: The one check box "Use Lambda Proxy Integration" on the Integration Request screen, if that is not checked my lambda event parameter was empty {}.  It took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

This has taken me awhile to figure out on my own so hoping this helps someone. After defining the Path Parameter on the Resource in API Gateway.

AWS Guide including PathParameter Steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html

If using CloudFormation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-parameter-error/

- My path `/user/{userId}`
- My Path Parameter: `userId`

[image: Integration Request API Gateway]

Then in my lambda function you can access the path via `event.path` which will have your parameters in object form: `path: { userId: 9812 } }`. Lots of documentation has it labeled as `pathParameters` but for whatever reason with this setup it doesn't come through that way.

```js
export const getUser = async (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  const { userId } = event.path;
}
```

serverless.yaml

```yaml
events:
      - http:
          path: user/{userId}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                userId: true
          integration: lambda
```