# AWS Lambda event.pathParameters is undefined and hence cannot destructure a property

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, path-parameter

I am triggering my lambda function from an api. The lambda function returns a query from a dynamoDB table,
I am passing an ID to in api.
but it returns an error.
"Cannot destructure property 'Id' of 'event.pathParameters' as it is undefined".

```js
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-south-1"})

exports.handler = async  (event, context)=> {
    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVerion: "2012-10-08"});
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-south-1"})

    let responseBody = ""
    let statusCode=""

    const { Id } =event.pathParameters;// to get the id from api 
    const params = {
        TableName: "User",
        Key:{
            // Id: "1"
            Id: Id
        }
    }

    try{
        const data = await documentClient.get(params).promise();
        // console.log(data);
        let x = data.Iteml
        responseBody = JSON.stringify
        statusCode = 200
    }
    catch(err){
        // console.log(err);
        responseBody = " Unable to get User data"
        statusCode= 403;

    }
    const response={
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers:{
            "myheader":"test"
        },
        body: responseBody
    }
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Can you print event object to cross check if id param is present or not, Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975944/aws-lambda-getting-path-parameters-using-node-js  if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same issue,
`event.pathParameters` was undefined, then got to know than use Lambda Proxy Integration is not checked during API creation.

**It should look as below in Integration request of API gateway**

[image: image1]