# Path parameters with NodeJS serverless

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, knative

I am learning serverless with nodejs. Right now a little bit confused. When I look at knative specifically, it is not clear to me how to handle path parameters.

In this [description](https://github.com/knative/func/blob/main/docs/function-templates/nodejs.md) , it is said that:

> Functions are invoked with a context object as the first parameter. This object provides access to the incoming request information. Developers can get the HTTP request method, any query strings sent with the request, the headers, the HTTP version, the request body.

Notice that they say nothing about path parameters. So my question: is this an accepted approach that nodejs functions/serverless do not support path parameters? Or am I missing something. Here is the example I have to extract query parameters:

```
const handle = async (context) => {
  const city = context.query.city;
};
```

Comment: path parameters are indeed possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975944/aws-lambda-getting-path-parameters-using-node-js

Comment: The question though is are knative and lambda aligned?